# Android drawLine alternative for performance improvement

Tags: android, performance, canvas

I'm working on a camera app, i'm showing the preview image luminosity histogram in a small rect (128x128 pix) overlying the live preview.

Sometimes an ANR happened, so i started using traceview to optimize my code (i'm doing some image manipulation on the fly, but it's very quick NEON asm & native code, no problem with it).

Using traceview i discovered that Canvas.drawLine() method is terribly slow. I have to update histogram 30 times per second in customView.onDraw(), drawing just 128 lines every frame. Incredibly, drawing 128 lines takes >8% cpu time (!!), when the entire native code to manipulate-convert the whole frame (720x480 yuv to ARGB_8888) takes <18%

I tried to draw the histogram on a new bitmap canvas then drawBitmap() it to the view's canvas but drawLine()s still take a lot of CPU.

I'm looking for an idea to avoid drawLine()...

I juts have to draw a small histogram from a int[128] normalized to 128

Here's my customView.onDraw (more or less...)

```
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int size = 128;
    int y = pos_y + size;
    int x;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if(histogram_data[i]>1) {
            x = pos_x+i;

            // this is the slow call!!
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, y-histogram_data[i], paint_histogram);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 without any comment!? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use Path instead of Lines.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply, i'll try it soon and let you know!

Comment: Tried with Path, it seems slightly better than drawing lines in a Bitmap's canvas as it avoids managing bitmaps, but it looks like moveTo()+lineTo() performs almost the same as drawLine())...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. What else you could do is to move moveTo() and lineTo() methods outside of draw(). Then draw() will just execute a single drawPath() method. As far as I know Android 4.0 and higher optimizes canvas calls by executing them in GPU.

Comment: Thanx again, another interesting idea! unfortunately moveTo() and lineTo() takes exactly the same CPU time, maybe inside onDraw() GPU executes only drawXXX() calls.

Comment: i accept this answer because drawPath is a single quick call inside the view's onDraw() method and doesn't need a Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [HERE](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render) they say the following:

> **Animating large Paths**
>
> When Canvas.drawPath() is called on the hardware accelerated Canvas
>   passed to Views, Android draws these paths first on CPU, and uploads
>   them to the GPU. If you have large paths, avoid editing them from
>   frame to frame, so they can be cached and drawn efficiently.
>   drawPoints(), drawLines(), and drawRect/Circle/Oval/RoundRect() are
>   more efficient – it's better to use them even if you end up using more
>   draw calls.

So you can try calling drawLines() once for drawing multiple lines at the same time instead of calling drawLine() for each line separately.

For me personally I had to draw 500+ lines, and I tried all available method for drawing line in canvas: drawPath(), drawLine() and drawLines(), but with all of them I felt enormous lagging on my phone, so the only available alternative was to use OpenGL ES. Here is a [example](https://github.com/slaviboy/OpenGLFingerGestureTransformations) I wrote using OpenGL for drawing large amount of lines, I tested it on my phone and it is smooth as butter. You can check the source code it is written in Kotlin, it also support finger gestures, that way you can Scale, Translate and Rotate the whole scene with your fingers. And I have included all basic shapes Rectangle, Triangle, Circle, Line, Polygon, and you can set shape coordinates as values between [-1,1], or with the familiar way using pixel values. If you want to learn more about OpenGL you can check [this post by the android team](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl).

Here is the result of the OpenGL example I wrote:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can add new layer on top and draw these 128 lines only once while leaving other pixels transparent.

Comment: of course it could be enough to refresh histogram at a slower frame rate, but i have to refresh it constantly to show user how exposition changes during camera preview. Anyway i'll try to implement this idea to see if GPU could speed it up, thanx!

Comment: same performance using another layer, anyway this was a good idea, i created a custom histogramView which i can manage apart. thanx

Comment: No. You could write them to a picture or something but overlapping views will cause a redraw on all the views.